# how to fix error "debugging resource strings are unavailable" 

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, xaml, hyperlink

I hope this is not very stupid question. i have textblock within runs i want to add hyperlink.

Someting like this

```
<Hyperlink NavigateUri="http://google.com">
<Run Text="http://google.com"/>
</Hyperlink>
```

I tried different approaches, but every time i had to add hyperlink, an error occurred.

`Error  2   [TextElementCollection_TypeNotSupportedInHost]
Arguments: 
Debugging resource strings are unavailable. 
Often the key and arguments provide sufficient information to diagnose the problem.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `TextBlock` control does not support `Hyperlink` child controls.
You should use a `RichTextBox` instead, like this:

```
<RichTextBox IsReadOnly="True">
    <Paragraph>
        Displaying text with
        <Hyperlink NavigateUri="http://www.google.com" TargetName="_blank">hyperlink</Hyperlink>.
    </Paragraph>
</RichTextBox>
```